# I get a Segmentation Fault error if I use 2 independent for loops, but if I use only one loop it works fine?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've got this structure (it is a node of a multiway tree)

```
typedef struct x{
    int id;
    struct x* son[MAX];
    int index;
}nodeR2;
```

And I have used a function to allocate memory and to initialize with NULL the pointers:

```
nodeR2* allocMemR2(int id)
{
    nodeR2* n = new nodeR2;
    if(n)
    {
        n->id = id;
        n->index = 0;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < MAX ; j++)
            n->son[j] = NULL;
        return n;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

The function works fine, I have tested it. But when I call a simple code like this in main():

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i ++)
        int x;



    nodeR2** root;
    *root = allocMemR2(2);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        int x;

    return 0;
}
```

It throws me a Segmentation fault error.
Please ignore the redundant instruction in the for loops, it is there only for demonstration purpose.
The funny thing is, if I remove ONE of the 2 for loops, the program works fine. This runs fine:

```
int main()
{
    // for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i ++)
    //     int x;



    nodeR2** root;
    *root = allocMemR2(2);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        int x;

    return 0;
}
```

What do 2 for loops have to do with my node and my allocation of memory and why it works if I remove either one of them?

Comment: `nodeR2** root` results in an uninitialized variable. `*root` has a high probability of crashing because it dereferences uninitialized memory.

Comment: Note that when you dereferences uninitialized memory that does not grantee a crash. The fact that it didn't crash was just pure luck. Also note that in c++ `nullptr` is prefered to `NULL` and there is no need for `typedef struct{...} T` you can have `struct T{...}`